# Listview items are not showing Popup menu

Tags: android, listview, adapter, popupwindow

My `listview` items are not showing popup menu also, they are not clicked.. Here is the my code please I need help.

```
public class AddMovieToList extends AppCompatActivity {
    MovieDbHelper helper;
    MyListAdapter adapter;
    ListView myDataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        helper = new MovieDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addtolist);


        myDataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addToList_listView);

        ArrayList<MovieModel> getInfos = helper.getMovieInfo();

        myDataList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new android.widget.PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(),view);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        if(adapter == null){
            adapter = new MyListAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.addlist_layout_type,getInfos);
            myDataList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else{
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(getInfos);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do the list appear the first time? i.e when the adapter is null?

Comment: Okey I just figured out the solution. It is originated because of my layout type